# Inform Jenkins about failed TestNG tests from Gradle run task to mark build as Failed

Tags: jenkins, gradle, testng, jenkins-pipeline

For the reasons I cannot influence, there is the following mechanism on TestNG launching on the project. 
In a word, it creates a new instance of TestNG, adds listeners, specifies classes and runs the tests. Then, all this dirty code is called from Gradle run task (which is actually empty and as far as I understood, simply calls the TestManager.main() method).

I removed the part of code just to show the main direction:

```
class TestManager {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            runTests(args[0])
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            System.in.read()
        }
    }

    private static void runTests(Application app) {

        TagsConfig.runs.each { run ->
            if (run.execute) {
                List<TagsSuite> suites = TagsConfig.suites
                suites.each { suite ->

                    if (suite.execute) {
                        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("${app.packageName}.${suite.name}")
                        def classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(${suite.name})

                        if (classes.size() > 0) {
                            TestNG testNG = new TestNG()
                            testNG.testClasses = classes
                            testNG.groupByInstances = true
                            testNG.outputDirectory = "testng-output"
                            testNG.addListener(new TestListenerAdapter())
                            testNG.addListener(new ExceptionListener())
                            testNG.addListener(new AllureTestListener())
                            if (TagsConfig.isSmoke) {
                                testNG.setGroups("smoke")
                            } else if (TagsConfig.isExtendedSmoke) {
                                testNG.setGroups("extended_smoke")
                            }
                            testNG.run()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So the test launch looks like this:

```
gradle clean
gradle run
```

I can not change the way the tests are started now and one of the problems is that the build in Jenkins is always Sucessful even if there are failed/broken/skipped tests.

So, I can get the number of failed tests from TestListenerAdapter, but how can I let Jenkins know that there were failed tests?

Maybe by returning an exit code from a Gradle run task or by installing some plugin that will check the count of failed tests in TestListenerAdapter?

For now, I'm setting a "FAILED_TESTS_COUNT" system property in onFinish() event and change the build status in pipeline if it is not 0, but this looks really dirty.

Jenkins 2.89.3
Gradle 3.5.1
TestNG 6.9.8

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the `Jenkins Text Finder post-build action`. In the above example, it looks for a pattern in the standard output and set the build to "unstable" (orange) when it's found.

In your case, just uncheck both checkboxes and find the according matching pattern.

[image: Jenkins Text Finder post-build action]

Comment: I hope, there should be a way to monitor TestNG results and to let Jenkins know about gradle task failure from the source code without parsing a final text log...

Comment: In my case, when at least one test was failing, the build failed (gradle was running test with a regular `test` task). I wanted the intermediate "unstable" state and this feature was the easiest way to achieve it.
As your tests are running in an hackish way, I thought this could help you.